# What is the difference between backticks (``) & double quotes ("") in golang?

Tags: string, go, quotes, string-literals, backticks

What is the difference between backticks (``` `` ```) & double quotes (`""`) in golang?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

In quotes `""` you need to escape new lines, tabs and other characters that do not need to be escaped in backticks ``` `` ```. If you put a line break in a backtick string, it is interpreted as a `'\n'` character, see https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals

Thus, if you say `\n` in a backtick string, it will be interpreted as the literal backslash and character n.

```
a := "\n" // This is one character, a line break.
b := `\n` // These are two characters, backslash followed by letter n.
```

Comment: So in C# terms backtick `` is like @"" while the double-quote "" is exactly like C# doublequote strings. That's neat. Shame though that the JS world employed backticks `` a few years down the road for string interpolation - something which at the time of this writing is not supported at all in GoLang. I'm saying this simple because JS is prevailing nowadays and it will make a lot of devs scratch their heads when they are picking up GoLang.

Answer (score 48):

Backtick strings are analogs of multiline raw string in Python or Scala: `r""" text """` or in JavaScript:

```
String.raw`Hi\u000A!`
```

They can:

1. Span multiple lines.
2. Ignore special characters.

They are useful:

1. For putting big text inside.
2. For regular expressions when you have lots of backslashes.
3. For struct tags to put double quotes in.

Answer (score 11):

**Raw** string literals are character sequences between backticks. **Backslashs** (`\`) have no special meaning  and **Carriage return** characters (`\r`) inside raw string literals are discarded from the raw string value.

**Interpreted** string literals are character sequences between double quotes (`\r`, `\n`, ...)

source: http://ispycode.com/GO/Strings/Raw-string-literals

Answer (score 9):

``` `` ``` represents an uninterpreted strings and `""` is an interpreted string.

> The value of a raw string literal *(uninterpreted strings)* is the string composed of the uninterpreted (implicitly UTF-8-encoded) characters between the quotes
>
> Interpreted string literals are character sequences between double quotes, as in "bar". Within the quotes, any character may appear except newline and unescaped double quote.

PS: italicized words are mine

https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals

Answer (score 7):

golang has three types of quotations. Single quote , double quote, or backquotes (backticks)

- Single quote - indicates a byte type or rune type which corresponds to uint8 or int32 as well as the default rune type. Usually used to denote rune types and display Unicode.
- Double quote - indicate strings which are char arrays. Hence you can use array index to access bytes or use functions like len().
- Back quotes (backtick) - indicate a string literal, but does not support escape sequences. Usually used to display string literals like multiple lines